# find the limit of the first one

Tags: numerical-methods

[image]

To prove the first one, can I just say that $\lim_{n\to\infty} {a^n/n^p}$= $(\lim_{n\to\infty} a^n)(\lim_{n\to\infty} 1/n^p)$ and when the absolute value of $a$ is less than or equal to one, $(\lim_{n\to\infty} a^n)=0$ so the limit of the whole sequence is $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost.  Your argument works for $|a|<1$, but if $a=\pm 1$ we don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty} a^n=0$.  Because $p>0$, however, $\lim_{n\to\infty} 1/n^p=0$.  That's because $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^p=\infty$ ($p$ fixed of course).  That gives us $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a^n/n^p|=0$ when $a=\pm 1$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty} a^n/n^p=0$ follows. Not sure what your Exercise 9.12 says.

Comment: oops you are right! I should have been more careful. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is something strange in your argue... The identity
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n b_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$$
is true if $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ converges. Therefore you must add that $\left(\frac{1}{n^p}\right)$ converges to $0$. Then your argue will work when $a=1$. If $a=-1$, then use that $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n|=0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$.